Are these two lines from Scott's audiobook scene in Quantumania present in the real-life memoir?
In Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania (2023), there's a humorous scene where Scott Lang is caught listening to the audiobook version of his own memoir, Look Out For The Little Guy! (which Marvel has also published as a real book). The scene plays out like this:




Hope: How about some music?
Car stereo: "And in that moment, all I could think was, 'How did the Hulk turn me into a baby?', 'Will I be a baby forever?', 'Am I the Hulk's baby?'"
Cassie: Dad, are you listening to your own book?
Car stereo: "But I was ready for anything."
Scott: Hmm? No, that's... It's just the radio.
Car stereo: "Steve and I grew close over that."
Cassie: Dad, turn it off.
Scott: It's so weird. Something's wrong with this switch. It won't turn off.
Cassie: I said turn it off.
Scott: What's that? Turn it up? All right.
Car stereo: "A little after that, a raccoon from space showed up. I don't think he knew my name. I was just happy to meet a raccoon who could talk."

I've checked the real-life version of Look Out For The Little Guy! and found the parts about the Hulk turning Scott into a baby and his encounter with Rocket (the talking raccoon from space).
However, I can't locate the lines "But I was ready for anything" or "Steve and I grew close over that." This isn't entirely surprising, as the earlier scene where Scott reads from his book also differs from the actual published version.
I'm wondering if these two lines appear somewhere in the real book, perhaps worded differently. If they do exist in the published version, which chapter can they be found in?
